# What should we do when we discover potential unusual behaviors?

Tags: automated-testing

We are testing a mock Simple Queue Service server.

From running test cases, it has been discovered that there are several "unusual behaviors"

- no exception thrown when message size boundary is exceeded
- illegal character can be transferred when it should not be allowed
- illegal message receipt handle can be sent to the server with no exception or error
- server can be configured with parameters much higher than its boundary with no exception or error
- missing attributes on the server
- queues should not be purged one after another, but in fact they can be.
- delay should be observed but there is none

They are different from a bug since this server is a 3rd party open source project, we are using it as a mock service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is really a good idea to test a 3rd party mock service before implementing it.

What I can suggest are:

1. Please review your test cases to see if they are really catching those unusual behaviors.
2. Document them with details, e.g. if the original boundary does not work, what is the new boundary or is there a boundary at all?
3. If it is an open source project, post those discoveries on its GitHub page (or something similar) and let the creators / users know.
4. Keeping those limitations in mind when using it as a mock service for your own project.

In my personal experiences, mock services always have some kind of drawbacks or limitations.